# Display time format on Liferay wiki comment must be in 24 format

Tags: java, liferay

I want to display time display of my wiki comment is in 24 format. how to do it
as if i comment on my wiki it displaying "custom_comment posted on 1:00pm" but it must be display "custom_comment posted on 13:00"

Answer (score 0):

It comes from `portal-web\docroot\html\taglib\ui\discussion\page.jsp`

You can override this jsp in hook and inside jsp code you can have your custom formatter defined to display 24 hours format.

NOTE: As this jsp is part of liferay-ui:discussion tag, it will get affected everywhere. Also based on className, you can have custom formatter only for Wiki.

Comment: nope its coming from theme\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\jsp\html\taglib\ui\discussion\page.jsp its a custom hook jsp to override wiki in custom document library portlet. Format dateFormatDateTime = FastDateFormatFactoryUtil.getDateTime(locale, timeZone);

Comment: :) I have mentioned jsp path in liferay-source not from tomcat